# AXWebBrowser Progress Bar Error

Tags: .net, vb.net, com

I am having trouble getting the progress bar1 in a tool strip to work correct. I intend to show the bar as the page loads.  my code is this:

```
Private Sub Webframe_ProgressChange(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AxSHDocVw.DWebBrowserEvents2_ProgressChangeEvent) Handles Webframe.ProgressChange


    If e.progress > -1 Then

        ToolStripProgressBar1.Maximum = Convert.ToInt32(e.progressMax)

        ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = Convert.ToInt32(e.progress)

    End If

End Sub
```

It works fine for a few page loads, then I get the following error:

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException
{"Value of '1020000' is not valid for 'Value'. 'Value' should be between 'minimum' and 'maximum'.
Parameter name: Value"}

When I look at the e.progress, the value is 1020000, whereas the progressmax is still 1000000.  Even If I assign maximum to be twice that amount, the problem still persists and errors on the value parameter.  Not sure if theres anything I can really do about it, since I am not assigning the value of e.progress or e.progressmax

Comment: ProgressChange has been broken for a while, don't use it.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I suppose I can just show an "endless" progress bar for this event, and then switch it out on document complete instead